# How to return same values of the array

Tags: php, arrays

I have question regarding PHP arrays (I'm kind a new to PHP, recently started education towards PHP&MySQL and I hit a bit of a wall here.

```
    $ljubimci_arr[]=array("naziv"=>"Štef","vrsta" => "Pas", "spol" => "M", "pasmina" => "vučjak","cijepljen" => true,"chip" =>"HRV20140115001" );
$ljubimci_arr[]=array("naziv"=>"Mia","vrsta" => "Macka", "spol" => "Ž", "pasmina" => "tazmanijska zvijer","cijepljen" => true, "chip" =>"HRV20140117002" );
$ljubimci_arr[]=array("naziv"=>"Štef","vrsta" => "Macka", "spol" => "M", "pasmina" => "ruska plava","cijepljen" => false, "chip" =>"HRV20140216003" );
$ljubimci_arr[]=array("naziv"=>"Thepas","vrsta" => "Pas", "spol" => "M", "pasmina" => "koker","cijepljen" => true, "chip" =>"HRV20140823004" );
$ljubimci_arr[]=array("naziv"=>"Rubick","vrsta" => "Macka", "spol" => "Ž", "pasmina" => "Škotski fold","cijepljen" => true, "chip" =>"HRV20140920005" );
$ljubimci_arr[]=array("naziv"=>"Svinjica","vrsta" => "Pas", "spol" => "Ž", "pasmina" => "samojed","cijepljen" => false, "chip" =>"HRV20141007006" );
$ljubimci_arr[]=array("naziv"=>"Aron","vrsta" => "Pas", "spol" => "M", "pasmina" => "mastif","cijepljen" => true, "chip" =>"HRV20150102007" );
```

I want to echo only values of the array that share same gender(in array "spol"

---

EDIT

When I try to get count of parameter "cijepljen" (boolean value) using

```
echo count(array_filter($ljubimci_arr));
```

I get this message:

> Warning: array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER
>   values!

How can I fix this?

---

EDIT

Everything fixed! Thx everyone!

Comment: use foreach to check the value of spol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean something like this:

```
$new = array();
$gender = 'M';
foreach($ljubimci_arr as $ar){
    if($ar['spol'] == $gender){
        $new[] = $ar;
    }
}
print_r($new);//array of only those with 'spol'=>'M'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So, basically I can do this for every element in array even true or false values?

Comment: No problem, yes, exactly

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I do have one simple question (and last one) regarding array above. How can I count how many are there **true** values?

Comment: just create new array with true values and use count() function which returns the number of array's values.